# odoo, how to reload widget on every db record form view?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-view

Hi this question is related with my own answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40499652/trying-to-show-chessboard-js-in-odoo-form-widget-no-error-no-pieces/40507277#40507277) the thing is that the widget run only once, when the first database record object is show on the form view, but when I change to another record, the view its not updated with the actual record. I think that is because I run all the code in the ´start´ but I dont know how and where put he code to do this.

the code again:

```
(function (instance) {
    var _t = instance.web._t,
        _lt = instance.web._lt;
    var QWeb = instance.web.qweb;

    openerp.chess_base = function (instance, local) {

        local.ShowBoard = instance.web.form.FormWidget.extend({
            start: function () {
                this.$el.append('<div id="board" style="width: 300px">BOARD GOES HERE</div>');
                this.show_board();
            },
            show_board: function () {
                var Game = new instance.web.Model("chess.game"),
                    record_id = this.field_manager.datarecord.id,
                    record_name = this.field_manager.datarecord.name,
                    self = this;
                    self.el_board = self.$('#board');

                Game.query(['pgn']).filter([['id', '=', record_id], ['name', '=', record_name]]).all().then(function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    self.cfg = {
                        position: data[0].pgn,
                        orientation: 'white',
                        pieceTheme: '/chess_base/static/img/chesspieces/wikipedia/{piece}.png'
                    };
                    ChessBoard(self.el_board, self.cfg);
                });
            }
        });

        instance.web.form.custom_widgets.add('board', 'instance.chess_base.ShowBoard');
    }
})(openerp);
```

Comment: I have encountered issues like this in the past. I never found a solution (although I am sure there is one) that I was really impressed with. However you could see if you can bind and event to a change in the browser's `hash` and then rerun your show_board function upon it firing. Please post your code if you find it. Or hopefully someone much smarter than me will post the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your *start* function:

```
this._ic_field_manager.on('view_content_has_changed', this, function() {
    'put your code here'
 })
```

EDIT:

Actually there's another event you could listen, *'load_record'*.
Because *'view_content_has_changed'* is triggered every time a single field in the view is modified, and you maybe don't want this behavior.